# doctrine 2 inner join troubles

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm trying ro execute this dql query
`SELECT DISTINCT a FROM Ipf\Model\Entity\Transaction t INNER JOIN t.idDonor a WHERE (t.idPost IN('3')) AND (t.status IN('completed'))`
And when I set hydration mode to **SCALAR** all works fine, but when I try to set hydration mode to **OBJECT**, I get this error:

```
E_NOTICE
Undefined index: t  
ObjectHydrator.php : 75
```

How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already had this can of issue because I tried to join using a property that was unidirectionnal and using it with the undefined direction.

Try to make your relation bi-directionnal. Can you also show us the model ?